# ¿Cómo tener n LOOPs anidados para combinar los elementos de muchos arreglos?

Tags: javascript

Durante estos últimos días me he enfocado en resolver la combinación de arreglos y guardar los resultado en otro arreglo. Obtengo el resultado esperado cuando ya se la cantidad de arreglos a combinar y sus `FOR` correspondientes, como es del código de abajo, pero se me dificulta cuando quiero codificar una función que tenga que recorrer un arreglo con arreglos anidados. He probado con recursividad y he avanzado algo, eso si, no se si sirve la recursividad para este caso.

Con el resultado del código de abajo hay que fijarse en el nombre completo del elemento, pues tiene el nombre se la asignatura "A*" y su sección "S*", lo escribo porque en un momento me confundí.

```js
function ejm() {
    let asignatura1 = ['A1S1', 'A1S5']
    let asignatura2 = ['A2S1', 'A2S5', 'A2S7']
    let asignatura3 = ['A3S2', 'A3S10']

    var t = []
    for (i = 0; i < asignatura1.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < asignatura2.length; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < asignatura3.length; k++) {
                t.push([asignatura1[i], asignatura2[j], asignatura3[k]])
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(t.length + ' combinaciones posibles')
    console.log(t)
}

ejm()
```

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Explicación de los arreglos anidados**

Cada arreglo es una asignatura o ramo de estudio, y en el, tiene sus elementos que son sus secciones. Referente a los arreglos de la función `ejm()`

- la `asignatura1` tiene 2 secciones
- la `asignatura2` tiene 3 secciones
- la `asignatura3` tiene 2 secciones

La idea es ir tomando una sección de cada asignatura e ir guardarlos, así poder ver todas las combinaciones posibles que existen. Con las  `asignatura1`, `asignatura2` y `asignatura3` presentan 12 combinaciones, pues es el resultado de multiplicar todas las secciones (2x3x2)

En matemáticas existe la combinación de elementos, en este caso lo nombro combinación de arreglos pues no encontré referencia a este caso en internet.

**Consideraciones**

- Se debe evitar la existencia de duplicados de asignaturas en una
  fila, por ejemplo: `['A1S1', 'A1S5', 'A2S1']`.
- En una fila deben estar todas las asignaturas.
- No se puede no excluir alguna asignatura.

**Lo que deseo**

Entonces, me gustaría pasarle un arreglo a una función en JavaScript que contenga `n` asignaturas con `n` secciones, para que los combine todos los elementos, como el del código de arriba.

Ejemplos de arreglos:

```
let asignaturasEjemplo1 = [
    ['A1S1', 'A1S5'],
    ['A2S1', 'A2S5', 'A2S7'],
    ['A3S2', 'A3S10']
]
```

o

```
let asignaturasEjemplo2 = [
    ['A1S1', 'A1S5'],
    ['A2S1', 'A2S5', 'A2S7']
]
```

o

```
let asignaturasEjemplo3 = [
    ['A1S1', 'A1S5'],
    ['A2S1', 'A2S5', 'A2S7'],
    ['A3S2', 'A3S10'],
    ['A4S1']
]
```

Comment: Lo de la combinacion es mucho mas dificil de realizar de lo que parece..., ya que enrealidad puede que hayan formas en las que un elemento se repita y no nos demos cuenta...

Comment: pero si quieres combinar varios array en un solo array. Tienes el método [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: @Riven Gracias por comentar. Entiendo el tema de la combinatoria en matemática, en el caso que propongo ningún elemento se se repite, como por ejemplo ['A1S1', 'A1S1', 'A3S2']

Comment: @hawks Gracias por tu comentario. [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) extrae y entrega todos los elementos del arreglo en uno solo, pero no los combina

Comment: @Isaías tienes razon en ambas cosas, de hecho justo iba a decir lo de flat, flat `NO` combina arreglos, los aplana.

Comment: @hawks gracias por mencionar .flat() porque lo use en otro contexto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función combinarGrupos() se dedica de realizar un recorrido del antepenúltimo al primer arreglo que se le entrega, pues como se ve en el resultado de la función ejm() esta presenta datos que se repiten, y, combinarGrupos() se basa en aquello.

[image: Muestra algunas variables que se usan]

```js
function combinarGrupos(a3) {

  // Se requiere formatear el ultimo arreglo que tiene, pues se requiere de asi para este código
  // let ultimoArreglo = a3[a3.length - 1]

  // Son todas las combinaciones que se realizan
  // let combinaciones = []
  
  // for (let h = 0; h < ultimoArreglo.length; h++) {
  //   combinaciones.push([ultimoArreglo[h]])
  // }

  // Son las combinaciones que se repiten en cada siclo, para luego entregárselas a la varible 'coombinaciones' 
  let combinacionesPrevias = []
  
  // Esta selección sirve para los arreglos que tienen solo elementos,
  // El proceso que esta comentado, me sirve cuando tengo que usar arreglos con objetos
  let combinaciones = a3[a3.length - 1]

  for (let i = a3.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (let j = 0; j < a3[i].length; j++) {
      for (let k = 0; k < combinaciones.length; k++) {
        let combinacionActual = [a3[i][j]].concat(combinaciones[k])
        // let combinacionActual = []
        // combinacionActual.push(a3[i][j])
        // for (let l = 0; l < combinaciones[k].length; l++) {
        //  combinacionActual.push(combinaciones[k][l])
        // }
        combinacionesPrevias.push(combinacionActual)
      }
    }
    combinaciones = combinacionesPrevias
    combinacionesPrevias = []
  }

  console.log("Cantidad de combinaciones realizadas: " + combinaciones.length)
  console.log(combinaciones)
}

let asignaturasEjemplo1 = [
  ['A1S1', 'A1S5'],
  ['A2S1', 'A2S5', 'A2S7'],
  ['A3S2', 'A3S10']
]
console.log('Combinaciones esperadas: ' + (2*3*2))
combinarGrupos(asignaturasEjemplo1)

let asignaturasEjemplo2 = [
    ['A1S1', 'A1S5'],
    ['A2S1', 'A2S5', 'A2S7']
]
console.log('Combinaciones esperadas: ' + (2*3))
combinarGrupos(asignaturasEjemplo2)

let asignaturasEjemplo3 = [
    ['A1S1', 'A1S5'],
    ['A2S1', 'A2S5', 'A2S7'],
    ['A3S2', 'A3S10'],
    ['A4S1']
]
console.log('Combinaciones esperadas: ' + (2*3*2*1))
combinarGrupos(asignaturasEjemplo3)
```

El código ejecutable de arriba solo muestra 4 combinaciones, pero en realidad son mas, ocurre lo mismo con la función ejm()

La formula para saber las cantidades de combinaciones de grupos; es la multiplicación de cada combinatoria sin repetición, `nCm = m!/n!(m-n)!`, donde `m`= es al largo del arreglo recorrido y `n` = es la cantidad de valores que se usarán, en este caso siempre se tomará 1, y siempre el resultado de esta combinatoria es igual a `m`. La multiplicación de las combinatorias, es decir, la multiplicación de cada arreglo anidado dará la cantidad de las combinaciones totales.

[Combinación de grupos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fg5UBWf2Rao)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para generar un arreglo nuevo. Dentro de la función recorres los arreglos internos para analizar si el elemento ya está en el arreglo a devolver o no.

Después de eliminar duplicados, intenta con la función que encontré en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61418166/2412893) (en inglés) para generar todas las posibles combinaciones, basado en la cantidad de elementos en el arreglo original:

```js
var a = [
    ['A1S1', 'A1S5'],
    ['A3S2', 'A3S10', 'A3S9', 'A3S7', 'A3S3', 'A3S8'],
    ['A2S1', 'S2S5', 'A3S7']
];


// Función encontrada en: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61418166/2412893
/**
 * Generate all combinations of an array.
 * @param {Array} sourceArray - Array of input elements.
 * @param {number} comboLength - Desired length of combinations.
 * @return {Array} Array of combination arrays.
 */
function generateCombinations(sourceArray, comboLength) {
  const sourceLength = sourceArray.length;
  if (comboLength > sourceLength) return [];

  const combos = []; // Stores valid combinations as they are generated.

  // Accepts a partial combination, an index into sourceArray, 
  // and the number of elements required to be added to create a full-length combination.
  // Called recursively to build combinations, adding subsequent elements at each call depth.
  const makeNextCombos = (workingCombo, currentIndex, remainingCount) => {
    const oneAwayFromComboLength = remainingCount == 1;

    // For each element that remaines to be added to the working combination.
    for (let sourceIndex = currentIndex; sourceIndex < sourceLength; sourceIndex++) {
      // Get next (possibly partial) combination.
      const next = [ ...workingCombo, sourceArray[sourceIndex] ];

      if (oneAwayFromComboLength) {
        // Combo of right length found, save it.
        combos.push(next);
      }
      else {
        // Otherwise go deeper to add more elements to the current partial combination.
        makeNextCombos(next, sourceIndex + 1, remainingCount - 1);
      }
        }
  }

  makeNextCombos([], 0, comboLength);
  return combos;
}

function combina(arr) {
    // Devolver un arreglo nuevo, sin duplicados, recorriendo todos los arreglos
    let ret = arr.reduce((acum, arr1) => {
        // Recorrer cada elemento de los arreglos internos
        arr1.forEach(item => {
            // Si aún no está en el arreglo final
            if(!acum.includes(item)) {
                // Agregarlo
                acum.push(item);
            }
        });
        return acum;
    }, []);
    // Devolver posibles combinaciones
    return generateCombinations(ret, arr.length);
}

console.log(combina(a));
```

Comment: Gracias @Triby por dedicar tiempo y compartir el código, ahora la idea es que salgan como el resultado del primer código que se puede ejecutar.

Comment: redacte una la explicación de lo que se puede hacer con el código del caso que presento, para ser mas clara su comprensión

Comment: Revisa la actualización, a ver si te sirve.

Comment: Bro, esta muy bueno el código y lo bueno que funciona, completamente no me sirve, ahora hay que afinarlo pues en una combinación no se pueden repetir las asignaturas, por ejemplo: `['A1S1', 'A1S5', 'A2S1']`, si uno le pasa 3 asignaturas que entregue las 3 asignaturas. Si le entrego al método la variable `asignaturasEjemplo1`  que entregue las 12 combinaciones como lo entrega el método `ejem()`. Me falto escribió eso en el enunciado, ya lo puse